# Is there a way to better optimize a hierarchical agglomerative clustering algorithm without using most sklearn libraries?

Tags: python, performance, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to write a hierarchical agglomerative clustering algorithm from scratch without using most of the related libraries, and my program does successfully put the test set into the closest clusters but takes a seemingly long time to run (~10mins). Here is the cProfile output, I'm not sure what exactly are the causes for some of the high tottimes and would love some input into where I should look to improve time efficiency:

```
1320454022 function calls (1297171889 primitive calls) in 604.103 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
243606900/241417078   30.434    0.000   57.228    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
  9482844   14.528    0.000   14.528    0.000 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
 54822154   10.950    0.000   26.284    0.000 generic.py:45(_instancecheck)
 54822154   10.643    0.000   15.061    0.000 generic.py:40(_check)
1458967/972740   10.290    0.000   58.878    0.000 base.py:430(__new__)
   486858    9.900    0.000   26.870    0.000 managers.py:1078(fast_xs)
 21154928    8.634    0.000   18.699    0.000 common.py:1591(_is_dtype_type)
  2674169    7.576    0.000  134.404    0.000 nanops.py:83(_f)
  1944854    7.418    0.000   11.237    0.000 stride_tricks.py:340(_broadcast_to)
  6322636    7.213    0.000   15.517    0.000 _ufunc_config.py:33(seterr)
  2674169    7.099    0.000   45.991    0.000 nanops.py:261(_get_values)
   486215    7.015    0.000    9.472    0.000 range.py:398(_get_indexer)
7782847/1218671    6.846    0.000  296.935    0.000 {built-in method numpy.core._multiarray_umath.implement_array_function}
  2917843    6.515    0.000   24.523    0.000 take.py:120(_take_nd_ndarray)
2432262/2432198    6.311    0.000   22.520    0.000 base.py:5464(equals)
47743101/36619491    6.290    0.000    8.913    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
 69009824    6.043    0.000    6.219    0.000 {built-in method builtins.getattr}
  1460196    6.036    0.000   48.981    0.000 series.py:342(__init__)
   486214    5.977    0.000   20.283    0.000 managers.py:572(_combine)
  1946498    5.851    0.000   10.922    0.000 generic.py:5844(__finalize__)
  1215996    5.706    0.000   89.043    0.000 base.py:3888(get_indexer)
  3890960    5.680    0.000   22.842    0.000 blocks.py:2172(new_block)
  2674155    5.587    0.000   33.097    0.000 nanops.py:1453(_maybe_null_out)
  6322636    5.125    0.000    5.758    0.000 _ufunc_config.py:132(geterr)
  1459231    4.800    0.000   15.693    0.000 construction.py:493(sanitize_array)
  2674155    4.654    0.000   95.078    0.000 nanops.py:588(nansum)
  2917843    4.550    0.000    9.061    0.000 take.py:554(_take_preprocess_indexer_and_fill_value)
3161043/729993    4.505    0.000  291.847    0.000 fromnumeric.py:69(_wrapreduction)
        1    4.350    4.350  601.255  601.255 HierarchicalAgglomerativeClustering.py:122(assign_clusters)
  5837217    4.299    0.000    8.814    0.000 common.py:585(is_dtype_equal)
   486302    4.233    0.000    6.175    0.000 {pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_objects}
 45231044    4.166    0.000    4.166    0.000 {built-in method builtins.issubclass}
   729781    4.162    0.000    4.162    0.000 {method 'get_indexer' of 'pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine' objects}
  2432861    3.878    0.000    5.037    0.000 generic.py:259(__init__)
   972546    3.842    0.000    5.662    0.000 {pandas._libs.lib.infer_dtype}
  4135330    3.734    0.000    9.282    0.000 common.py:1278(is_bool_dtype)
  3891187    3.660    0.000    6.732    0.000 blocks.py:2091(maybe_coerce_values)
 13127712    3.586    0.000    7.505    0.000 nanops.py:86(<genexpr>)
  5740683    3.571    0.000   13.593    0.000 {built-in method builtins.any}
  3160680    3.567    0.000    3.567    0.000 {method 'take' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
  2917843    3.538    0.000   28.902    0.000 take.py:57(take_nd)
   243224    3.518    0.000    3.518    0.000 {method 'argsort' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
   486210    3.484    0.000  261.926    0.001 frame.py:10773(_reduce)
  3891134    3.459    0.000    4.506    0.000 blocks.py:2120(get_block_type)
 15809764    3.444    0.000    5.137    0.000 common.py:1556(get_dtype)
   243105    3.396    0.000   20.376    0.000 arraylike.py:244(array_ufunc)
  3890960    3.324    0.000    5.610    0.000 blocks.py:2186(check_ndim)
  1215846    3.315    0.000   11.407    0.000 common.py:235(asarray_tuplesafe)
  2431050    3.265    0.000  142.196    0.000 blocks.py:355(reduce)
  9969100    3.240    0.000    4.836    0.000 common.py:156(<lambda>)
  5834796    3.212    0.000   10.198    0.000 common.py:684(is_integer_dtype)
 26218848    3.143    0.000    3.143    0.000 blocks.py:827(iget)
  6322754    3.127    0.000    8.934    0.000 common.py:162(is_object_dtype)
  2431597    3.110    0.000   32.803    0.000 blocks.py:861(take_nd)
  2674155    3.077    0.000   98.155    0.000 nanops.py:469(newfunc)
   486210    2.949    0.000  207.908    0.000 managers.py:1546(reduce)
   972441    2.940    0.000    8.659    0.000 base.py:1168(take)
   729315    2.936    0.000  287.881    0.000 generic.py:11443(_min_count_stat_function)
13133174/12646466    2.914    0.000    3.147    0.000 {built-in method numpy.asarray}
  2677912    2.807    0.000    9.943    0.000 generic.py:5904(__setattr__)
 20801040    2.793    0.000    3.028    0.000 {built-in method builtins.hasattr}
  4863074    2.755    0.000    7.346    0.000 common.py:1246(is_float_dtype)
  2674169    2.724    0.000  100.880    0.000 nanops.py:403(new_func)
  6323277    2.643    0.000   14.210    0.000 base.py:286(is_dtype)
 10453543    2.630    0.000    3.919    0.000 nanops.py:79(check)
  2188541    2.512    0.000    3.808    0.000 base.py:690(_simple_new)
  5351062    2.442    0.000    2.779    0.000 construction.py:461(ensure_wrapped_if_datetimelike)
  2431050    2.160    0.000  122.672    0.000 frame.py:10819(blk_func)
 10213169    2.157    0.000    2.925    0.000 base.py:925(__len__)
   729315    2.151    0.000    2.151    0.000 base.py:2313(is_monotonic_increasing)
  4700329    2.131    0.000   12.898    0.000 construction.py:399(extract_array)
  2676720    2.083    0.000    6.626    0.000 series.py:661(name)
  4864046    2.073    0.000   12.864    0.000 common.py:501(is_categorical_dtype)
   729995    2.059    0.000   66.363    0.000 indexing.py:1592(_getitem_axis)
 11185828    2.017    0.000    2.934    0.000 common.py:148(<lambda>)
   486463    1.990    0.000    4.474    0.000 base.py:2381(is_unique)
  2431550    1.952    0.000    3.540    0.000 missing.py:460(array_equivalent)
   486985    1.950    0.000   38.409    0.000 frame.py:3703(_ixs)
  1459101    1.919    0.000    8.229    0.000 base.py:6205(_maybe_promote)
   488394    1.894    0.000    2.843    0.000 numerictypes.py:573(_can_coerce_all)
  2674169    1.894    0.000   16.879    0.000 nanops.py:217(_maybe_get_mask)
  3161318    1.884    0.000    9.050    0.000 _ufunc_config.py:435(__exit__)
  3161318    1.881    0.000   10.233    0.000 _ufunc_config.py:430(__enter__)
  1459214    1.814    0.000    3.496    0.000 construction.py:744(_try_cast)
  6321398    1.810    0.000    2.453    0.000 common.py:1154(needs_i8_conversion)
  4380185    1.804    0.000    2.928    0.000 series.py:611(name)
   729315    1.800    0.000    4.804    0.000 _validators.py:168(validate_args_and_kwargs)
  4134961    1.767    0.000    1.767    0.000 {built-in method numpy.empty}
   243106    1.757    0.000    2.948    0.000 utils.py:243(maybe_convert_indices)
  2431050    1.721    0.000    8.281    0.000 fromnumeric.py:2333(any)
  7411428    1.713    0.000    1.768    0.000 {pandas._libs.lib.is_list_like}
 11185828    1.699    0.000    1.699    0.000 common.py:146(classes)
   486462    1.695    0.000   37.785    0.000 managers.py:689(reindex_indexer)
  6322636    1.664    0.000    1.664    0.000 {built-in method numpy.seterrobj}
   486426    1.633    0.000    9.233    0.000 numeric.py:132(_ensure_array)
  1216518    1.622    0.000    2.848    0.000 warnings.py:181(_add_filter)
  1948069    1.617    0.000    1.918    0.000 managers.py:2069(internal_values)
   972722    1.599    0.000    6.376    0.000 base.py:588(_dtype_to_subclass)
  3403518    1.592    0.000    8.830    0.000 {method 'sum' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
  9969100    1.564    0.000    1.564    0.000 common.py:151(classes_and_not_datetimelike)
   973100    1.562    0.000  183.187    0.000 indexing.py:1059(__getitem__)
   486465    1.548    0.000   25.661    0.000 base.py:708(_with_infer)
   243105    1.535    0.000   22.532    0.000 base.py:3358(_union)
 12645272    1.515    0.000    1.515    0.000 {built-in method numpy.geterrobj}
 12158014    1.511    0.000    1.512    0.000 base.py:5090(_values)
  3891396    1.507    0.000   27.928    0.000 base.py:7277(ensure_index)
  5108897    1.501    0.000    2.124    0.000 inference.py:325(is_hashable)
  1216000    1.487    0.000   13.618    0.000 base.py:6285(_should_compare)
  1216518    1.478    0.000    1.635    0.000 warnings.py:458(__enter__)
   972658    1.474    0.000    1.952    0.000 managers.py:1061(from_blocks)
   486428    1.474    0.000   34.274    0.000 managers.py:751(<listcomp>)
   729385    1.447    0.000    2.289    0.000 missing.py:268(_isna_array)
  2917843    1.446    0.000    1.446    0.000 take.py:326(_get_take_nd_function)
  2431130    1.438    0.000   15.226    0.000 blocks.py:221(make_block)
  2431615    1.414    0.000    1.414    0.000 blocks.py:236(make_block_same_class)
3652387/3652373    1.398    0.000    4.249    0.000 {built-in method builtins.all}
  1945226    1.381    0.000    1.831    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1053(_handle_fromlist)
  1215996    1.381    0.000   10.228    0.000 base.py:4020(_check_indexing_method)
  2674804    1.379    0.000    2.136    0.000 common.py:1433(is_extension_array_dtype)
  2431050    1.375    0.000   11.987    0.000 <__array_function__ internals>:177(any)
  2432012    1.353    0.000    4.507    0.000 base.py:7372(maybe_extract_name)
  2917827    1.352    0.000    1.352    0.000 cast.py:527(maybe_promote)
   243105    1.346    0.000   68.753    0.000 base.py:4561(join)
   486211    1.344    0.000    2.803    0.000 numeric.py:2407(array_equal)
  2431156    1.334    0.000    1.334    0.000 {built-in method numpy.array}
    80080    1.321    0.000    2.861    0.000 managers.py:1183(iset)
   243137    1.317    0.000   36.436    0.000 generic.py:5332(_reindex_with_indexers)
  5105746    1.313    0.000    1.313    0.000 range.py:353(dtype)
  2674169    1.297    0.000    2.395    0.000 nanops.py:350(_na_ok_dtype)
   973155    1.276    0.000    3.079    0.000 config.py:116(_get_single_key)
   486465    1.275    0.000    3.493    0.000 warnings.py:130(filterwarnings)
  1620171    1.267    0.000    1.584    0.000 managers.py:1891(__init__)
  2676738    1.263    0.000    4.544    0.000 common.py:1725(validate_all_hashable)
   243565    1.251    0.000   21.485    0.000 base.py:1316(_arith_method)
  3161043    1.246    0.000    1.246    0.000 fromnumeric.py:70(<dictcomp>)
   243105    1.236    0.000  107.349    0.000 generic.py:9530(_align_series)
   972879    1.227    0.000    1.821    0.000 _dtype.py:344(_name_get)
  3160891    1.216    0.000    7.052    0.000 {method 'any' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
  2917898    1.213    0.000    1.775    0.000 common.py:1487(is_ea_or_datetimelike_dtype)
   243741    1.212    0.000    1.485    0.000 managers.py:1097(<listcomp>)
  2432262    1.201    0.000    1.548    0.000 base.py:839(is_)
   244197    1.190    0.000    7.527    0.000 cast.py:1589(find_common_type)
  1702649    1.187    0.000    3.148    0.000 common.py:1204(is_numeric_dtype)
  1607740    1.185    0.000    1.566    0.000 generic.py:564(_get_axis)
   486463    1.182    0.000    2.484    0.000 base.py:881(_engine)
  1022189    1.162    0.000    4.059    0.000 common.py:96(is_bool_indexer)
  2432861    1.159    0.000    1.159    0.000 flags.py:49(__init__)
   972665    1.157    0.000    3.676    0.000 frame.py:609(__init__)
   486214    1.152    0.000    1.152    0.000 {pandas._libs.lib.get_reverse_indexer}
  5353476    1.147    0.000    2.190    0.000 common.py:1744(<genexpr>)
   972441    1.138    0.000    3.190    0.000 algorithms.py:1484(take)
  1461015    1.125    0.000    1.125    0.000 generic.py:5888(__getattr__)
  1945051    1.114    0.000    3.293    0.000 take.py:502(_take_nd_object)
   810364    1.102    0.000    2.747    0.000 base.py:54(shape)
  1944854    1.087    0.000   13.984    0.000 <__array_function__ internals>:177(broadcast_to)
  2511149    1.075    0.000    1.075    0.000 {method 'reshape' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
   972972    1.065    0.000    8.493    0.000 managers.py:1934(from_array)
  3160891    1.046    0.000    5.835    0.000 _methods.py:55(_any)
  1216028    1.031    0.000    4.330    0.000 dtypes.py:1247(is_dtype)
   243105    1.019    0.000   73.572    0.000 base.py:6056(_get_indexer_strict)
```

Here is the program as a reference, I apologize in advance for messy syntax and poor documentation:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import zscore
from scipy.io.arff import loadarff
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances
import cProfile

def load_file():
    '''
    :return: df that is of the same form of past dfs after you use loadarff
    '''
    data, meta = loadarff('adult-big.arff')
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    i = 0
    for dtype in df.dtypes:
        if dtype == object:
            df[df.columns[i]] = df[df.columns[i]].str.decode("utf-8")
        i += 1
    length = df.shape[0]
    df['cluster'] = [0 for i in range(length)]
    df_train = df.sample(n = int(np.sqrt(length)), random_state=1).reset_index(drop=True)
    df_test = df.drop(df_train.index).reset_index(drop=True)

    return df_train, df_test

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def pre_process_data(df_train, df_test):
    '''
    :param df: dataframe that has been loaded from load_file()
    :return: df that has been cleaned
    '''

    df_means_and_modes = []
    df_train_class = df_train['class']
    df_test_class = df_test['class']

    for column in df_train:

        if df_train[column].dtype == object:

            mask_train = df_train[column] == '?'
            mask_test = df_test[column] == '?'
            df_mode = df_train.groupby('class')[column].apply(lambda x: x.mode().iloc[0])
            df_means_and_modes.append(str(df_mode[0]))
            df_train.loc[mask_train, column] = str(df_mode[0])
            df_test.loc[mask_test, column] = str(df_mode[0])
            df_train[column].fillna(df_mode, inplace=True)
            df_test[column].fillna(df_mode, inplace=True)

        else:

            df_mean = df_train.groupby('class')[column].apply(lambda x: x.mean())
            df_means_and_modes.append(df_mean)
            df_train[column].fillna(df_mean, inplace=True)
            df_test[column].fillna(df_mean, inplace=True)
            df_train[column] = zscore(df_train[column])
            df_test[column] = zscore(df_test[column])

    df_train = df_train.drop(columns=['class'])
    df_test = df_test.drop(columns=['class'])
    df_train = pd.get_dummies(df_train)
    df_test = pd.get_dummies(df_test)

    df_train['cluster'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
    df_test['cluster'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

    return df_train, df_test, df_train_class, df_test_class

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def calculate_distance_matrix(df):
    '''
    :param df: dataframe that has been converted to numerical values
    :return: distance matrix
    '''

    distance_matrix = euclidean_distances(df, df)
    distance_matrix = np.tril(distance_matrix)
    distance_matrix = np.where(distance_matrix < 2e-07, np.inf, distance_matrix)
    return distance_matrix

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def find_min_distance(distance_matrix):
    '''
    :param distance_matrix: distance matrix
    :return: row and column of the minimum distance in the distance matrix
    '''

    min_distance = np.min(distance_matrix)
    row, col = np.where(distance_matrix == min_distance)
    return int(row[0]), int(col[0])

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def hierarchical_agglomerative_clustering(distance_matrix, df_original, df_copy, k):
    '''

    :param distance_matrix:
    :param k:
    :return:
    '''

    length = distance_matrix.shape[0]
    cluster_id = 0
    for i in range(length - k):
        row, col = find_min_distance(distance_matrix)
        new_length = length - i
        df_original.loc[df_original.index[int(row)], 'cluster'] = cluster_id
        df_original.loc[df_original.index[int(col)], 'cluster'] = cluster_id
        cluster_id += 1
        df_copy.iloc[row] += df_copy.iloc[col]
        df_copy.iloc[row] /= 2
        df_copy = df_copy.drop(df_copy.index[col])
        distance_matrix = calculate_distance_matrix(df_copy)

    return distance_matrix, df_original, df_copy

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def assign_clusters(df_test, clusters):
    # For each sample in df_test, find the closest cluster by euclidean distance and assign it to that cluster
    for i in range(df_test.shape[0]):
        min_distance = np.inf
        for j in range(clusters.shape[0]):
            test_sample = np.sum(df_test.loc[[i]])
            cluster_sample = np.sum(clusters.iloc[[j]])
            distance = np.sum(np.square(test_sample - cluster_sample))
            distance = np.sqrt(distance)
            if distance < min_distance:
                min_distance = distance
                cluster = j
        df_test.loc[df_test.index[i], 'cluster'] = cluster

    return df_test


# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def main():

    k = 5
    df_train, df_test = load_file()
    df_train_copy = df_train
    df_test_copy = df_test
    df_train_copy, df_test_copy, df_train_class, df_test_class = pre_process_data(df_train_copy, df_test_copy)
    distance_matrix = calculate_distance_matrix(df_train_copy)
    distance_matrix, df_train, clusters = hierarchical_agglomerative_clustering(distance_matrix, df_train, df_train_copy, k)
    df_test_copy = assign_clusters(df_test_copy, clusters)
    print(df_train['cluster'].nunique())

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # main()
    cProfile.run('main()', sort='time')
```

Comment: narrow down your problem using `line_profiler` if you use pycharm, there is [plugin you can use](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16536-line-profiler)

Comment: I don't have a certain answer for you, but I could identify some slow code and malpractice:
1- Never use get_dummies (it has so many issues with not encoding values that are not mutual between train and test sets). 2- Use for loop if you have a small list, otherwise pandas functions are much faster (use pd.assign()). 3- try to avoid pd.apply(), it is very slow, check out online for alternatives like pd.map() or pd.assign().  Finally, you have really good code! I hope you find this comment helpful.